# Создание таблицы в базе данных wordpress

Tags: база-данных, wordpress, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Решил поучиться создавать плагины под вордпресс, и начинаются первые тупики. Для плагина необходимо создать таблицу в базе данных wordpress.

```
    function get_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql_create_params = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $wpdb->prefix . "create_params` (
                `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `shrocode` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
              );";}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'get_table');
```

Но таблица не создается.

Подскажите, в чем проблема.

Comment: В том, что запрос не вызывается, а хук подключается внутри функции, которую он же и регистрирует?

Comment: @Etki, запости ответ как ответ.

Comment: Это я здесь ошибся, код же не совсем живой оказался, сейчас поправлю. В оригинале функция заканчивается до хука. Ради эксперимента я хук вынес вверх, даже реакция нулевая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведённая функция делает только одно: создаёт локальную переменную `$sql_create_params`, в которую кладёт SQL-команду, которая, по замыслу, должна создать нужную таблицу. Потом функция завершается. Команда при этом не исполняется, с чего бы ей исполняться-то?

Comment: register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'get_table');
Это же хук который запускает функцию.

Comment: Да, и всё, что делает эта функция, - это создаёт локальную переменную (переменная существует только внутри функции, по завершении работы функции переменная прекращает существование). Недостаточно положить SQL команду в переменную, что бы php отправил эту команду на SQL-сервер.

Comment: А что надо? Не подскажите, вот что мне надо добавить? Просто вот здесь как раз и говориться, что хук - это и есть вызов функци, и для созданиии таблицы достаточно http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B:_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%91%D0%94

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте раздел "Создание или Обновление таблицы" (там всё неплохо разжовано, вроде) и то, что я вам написал.

Ваша функция, скорее всего, вызывается. Но любая функция, будучи вызванной, делает не то, что нам бы от неё хотелось, а то, на что она запрограммирована. Ваша функция запрограммирована только на создание переменной, содержащей определённую строку, но не на выполнение SQL-запросов.

Comment: Не буду давать вам готовый ответ, он уже есть в приведённой вами статье. При разработке плагинов вам ещё не раз придётся решать задачу вдумчивого чтения документации, так лучше отточите этот навык "на кошках" (на хорошей, и даже русскоязычной, странице кодекса).

Comment: Вы имеете в виду вот эту строку функции?   
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
      dbDelta($sql);
Так все равно не работает.

Comment: В той статье говорится, что функция `dbDelta()` весьма придирчива, возможно, ей что-то не нравится в том SQL-запросе. Можно, конечно, сделать запрос напрямую, но лучше разобраться, что там не так. Включите в WP режим отладки (гуглить WP debug) и смотрите, какие возникают ошибки при установке плагина (или когда там ваша функция вызывается).

Comment: В целом спасибо, вы мне помогли, хотя я так и не понял, почему не действовал мой код.